# how to set tab bar background image to clear image

Tags: swift, xcode, image, uitabbar, tabbar

i want to set the tab bar image to be clear img without any colors or any background only shows the tab bar bottoms i tried a lot of code but its still shows me white background

this is my code in appdelegate

```
        UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
        UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.clear
        UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor.HalaColor
        UITabBar.appearance().layer.borderWidth = 0.50
        UITabBar.appearance().clipsToBounds = true
```

Answer (score 3):

With the following lines you should get the effect you are looking for:

```
UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.clear
UITabBar.appearance().shadowImage = UIImage()
UITabBar.appearance().backgroundImage = UIImage()
```

Comment: Once set the shadowImage and backgroundImage, how to get back to default values? I need to do that when using UIdocumentPicker and UIDocumentInteractionController.

Comment: Found solution: I set them to nil